# How to use CASE WHEN THEN ELSE in tortoise orm

Tags: python, sql, orm, tortoise-orm

Hi I'm trying to use CASE WHEN THEN ELSE in tortoise-orm.
I tried the following but didn't work:

```py
import datetime
import tortoise.models
import tortoise.fields
import tortoise.expressions
from pypika import Case

class Task(tortoise.models.Model):
    uid = tortoise.fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    name = tortoise.fields.CharField(255)
    name_updated_at = tortoise.fields.data.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

await Task.filter(uid="my-super-uid").update(
    name=Case()
    .when(tortoise.expressions.F('name_updated_at') > datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "Hi")
    .else_(tortoise.expressions.F('name'))
)
```

I know CASE is [supported by pypika](https://github.com/kayak/pypika#case-statements), but I don't know how to use it in tortoise-orm.
Also I do want to use CASE because I want to use cases for multiple fields in a single update, instead of making multiple updates with different `filter(...)` parameters.

Any idea how to use `CASE()`??